# Generate start and end dates for each week of a year starting from any date with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I recently came across an app https://entire.life which shows a calendar like the images below in which it shows a row of dots for each year of your life.

The row of dots is 52 dots wide, 1 dot per week for that rows year.

Each row is a year.

Each rows 1st dot week date starts on the week of your birth date and not on January 1st of the year.  So the row of week dots is 1 year per row starting and ending on your birthdate week.

The last image below shows that week dots that are in the future of todays date are shown as a grey dot to indicate that these weeks have not occured yet.

Here is a live example from the images above to see dit in action https://entire.life/jason-davis

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne07D.png
[image]

---

This image below shows a form to add events for the current week dot that was clicked on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5BUT.png
[image]

---

This image shows how the week dots for future dates are grey.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYGAn.png
[image]

---

**QUESTION**

Using PHP I would like to generate a calendar like this based on a users birthdate like the above shown app.

Here is a live example from the images above to see dit in action https://entire.life/jason-davis

**Rules:**

- Generate a row of dots representing each week of the year
- Generate a row of the above week year dots for 100 years worth of rows starting on the users birth date year.
- The starting week dot for each row should start on the users birth date week and not on January 1st of the year.

Using PHP's DateTime functions how can I determine the start and end dates for each of the 52 weeks based on a users birth date?

My birthdate in the example here is April 21 1983
The 1st years week dots represent these dates based on that start date:

**1st row of year dots**
- 21 – 27 Apr 1983  - 0 years old
- 28 Apr – 4 May 1983  - 0 years old
- 5 – 11 May 1983  - 0 years old
- 12 – 18 May 1983  - 0 years old
- 19 – 25 May 1983  - 0 years old
- 26 May – 1 Jun 1983  - 0 years old
- 2 – 8 Jun 1983  - 0 years old
- 9 – 15 Jun 1983  - 0 years old
- 16 – 22 Jun 1983  - 0 years old
- 23 – 29 Jun 1983  - 0 years old
- ...
- ... 
- ...
- 29 Mar – 4 Apr 1984  - 0 years old
- 5 – 11 Apr 1984  - 0 years old
- 12 – 18 Apr 1984  - 0 years old
- 19 – 20 Apr 1984  - 0 years old

**2nd row of year dots**
- 21 – 27 Apr 1984 1 year old
- 28 Apr – 4 May 1984  - 1 years old
- 5 – 11 May 1984  - 1 years old
- 12 – 18 May 1984  - 1 years old
- 19 – 25 May 1984  - 1 years old
- 26 May – 1 Jun 1984  - 1 years old
- 2 – 8 Jun 1984  - 1 years old
- 9 – 15 Jun 1984  - 1 years old
- 16 – 22 Jun 1984  - 1 years old
- 23 – 29 Jun 1984  - 1 years old
- ...
- ...
- ...
- 29 Mar – 4 Apr 1985  - 1 years old
- 5 – 11 Apr 1985  - 1 years old
- 12 – 18 Apr 1985  - 1 years old
- 19 – 20 Apr 1985  - 1 years old

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero effort in attempting to solve the problem. Basically you're asking "can you write this code for me?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
<?php 
   $userBirthDate = "1990-10-02"; // You probably use data from database or POST or GET, I setted a static one just for the example 
   $wishedDate = new DateTime($userBirthDate); // Here, you can add any desired date as an argument to DateTime, by default, it'll take the current DateTime.
   // This is for 100 years
   for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++){
     echo '<hr>'; // Just so every year will be separated by a html horizontal bar
     $limit = 52; // 52 for a year, but you could do as much as you need right there
     for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++){
       echo $wishedDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Write the current date
       echo '<br />'; // Just to switch line
       $wishedDate->modify('+1 week'); // Add one week to the wished date 
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: It's my pleasure ! Don't forget to accept the answer if it feels right to you :-) !

Comment: Would you mind helping to further modify to now take this and count up 100 years so basically 100 rows of this constantly counting up at this rate? Like this does https://entire.life/jason-davis

Comment: Sure I can help you with this Jason, I'll update the script to help you

Comment: Perhaps just increasing the `$limit` to `$limit * 100` would be the answer and then adding code to do a new row after every 52 is the solution

Comment: @JasonDavis there you go, I did another loop for 100 year, and seperating it with a hr for clarity !